# Find the area of the region bounded above by the curve...

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region bounded above by the curve $x^2+y^2=2$ and below by the curve $y=x^2$.

[image] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ckbd.png))

Here's my attempt:

Since $y =x^2$, then $x^2+x^2=2$, which simplifies to give $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Since $y^2=2-x^2$, then $y=\sqrt( 2-x^2)$. Finally, I tried to integrate $\sqrt (2-x^2)-x^2$ and I got area $\pi/2 $ as my answer.         Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!

Comment: Why did you choose $y=+\sqrt{2-x^2}$ and not $y=-\sqrt{2-x^2}$? As far as your definite integral is concerned you can use wolfram alpha to check if it is indeed $\pi/2$ (or not).

Comment: It is completely unclear what to do here. First, the first curve is a circle and doesn't bound a region "from above". Second, are we supposed to consider only the region above the x-axis? And third, shall we also consider the region which is enclosed by the circle above (and below?) $[-\sqrt 2,-1]$ and $[1,\sqrt 2]$?

Comment: I thought you always take the positive root...

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Those two curves divide the plane into four regions. One of those regions is bounded above by an arc of the circle and bounded below by an arc of the parabola. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, now I realize that, thank you. In my answer both possibilities are included now.

Comment: Alright, got it. However, both curves also enclose another region which I was focused on for some reason.

Comment: It turns out the positive root is the one you want, but only because the boundary of your desired region happens to be the upper semicircle. If any part of the lower semicircle were involved in the boundary of the region, you would need to consider the negative root (or use a different approach altogether). You did not show the steps of how you integrated $\sqrt{2-x^2} - x^2$, so it's not clear how you got the answer $\pi/2$; that's the area of the pie-slice shape bounded below by $y=|x|$ and above by $x^2+y^2=2$, clearly less than the area of the region you need.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\left(\sqrt{2-x^2}-x^2\right)\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^1\left(\sqrt{2-x^2}-x^2\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=4\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos^2(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta-\frac23\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/4}(\cos(2\theta)+1)\,\mathrm{d}\theta-\frac23\\[3pt]
&=\frac\pi2+\frac13\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the calculation of the area between $\;y=x^2\;$ below and $\;x^2+y^2=2\;$ above:

Since both $\;y=\sqrt{2-x^2}\;,\;\;y=x^2\;$ are even functions, and since also

$\;y=\sqrt{2-x^2}=x^2\iff x=\pm1\;$ , the area is given by

$$A=2\int_0^1\left(\sqrt{2-x^2}-x^2\right)dx=2\sqrt2\int_0^1\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}\right)^2}\,dx-\left.\frac23x^3\right|_0^1$$

Substitute in the last integral $\sin u=\frac x{\sqrt2}\implies \sqrt2\,\cos u\,du=dx\;$ , and we get

$$A=4\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos^2u\,du-\frac23=\left.4\left(\frac{u+\sin u\cos u}2\right)\right|_0^{\pi/4}-\frac23=2\left(\frac\pi4+\frac12\right)-\frac23=\frac\pi2+\frac13$$

Now, if you want the area inside the disk $\;x^2+y^2\le2\;$ and below the parabola $\;y=x^2\;$, we have to substract the above from the disk's area:

$$2\pi-\left(\frac\pi2+\frac13\right)=\frac{3\pi}2-\frac13$$

Comment: There is a typo in the end. It should be $1/3$ and not $-1/3$.

Comment: @Jack Thank you very much. Edited.

Comment: The mistake is earlier than that: $2(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac12)-\frac23 = \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac13$.

Comment: Don't you get x^3/3 when you integrate x^2? How did you get 2x^3/3?

Comment: @Zeus579 Because it is all multiplied by $\;2\;$ . Thank you.

Comment: @TonyK Again, thanks a lot. Hopefully this time I stopped making first grade mistakes.

Comment: Okay thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

We get the following integrals:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{2-x^2}\space\text{d}x-\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\space\text{d}x=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{2-x^2}\space\text{d}x-\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-1}^{1}=$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{2-x^2}\space\text{d}x-\frac{1}{3}\left[x^3\right]_{-1}^{1}=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{2-x^2}\space\text{d}x-\frac{1^3-(-1)^3}{3}=$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{2-x^2}\space\text{d}x-\frac{2}{3}=$$

---

Substitute $x=\sin(u)\sqrt{2}$ and $\text{d}x=\sqrt{2}\cos(u)\space\text{d}u$.

Then $\sqrt{2-x^2}=\sqrt{2-2\sin^2(u)}=\sqrt{2}\cos(u)$ and $u=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

This gives a new lower bound $u=\arcsin\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and upper bound $u=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$:

---

$$2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos^2(u)\space\text{d}u-\frac{2}{3}=$$

---

Use the identity $\cos^2(x)=\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$:

---

$$2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\frac{\cos(2u)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right]\space\text{d}u-\frac{2}{3}=2\left[\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}1\space\text{d}u\right]-\frac{2}{3}=$$
$$2\left[\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{1}{2}\left[u\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=2\left[\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}--\frac{\pi}{4}}{2}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=$$
$$2\left[\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}}{2}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=2\left[\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{\frac{2\pi}{4}}{2}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=$$
$$2\left[\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=$$

---

Substitute $s=2u$ and $\text{d}s=2\space\text{d}u$.

This gives a new lower bound $s=2\cdot-\frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and upper bound $s=2\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$:

---

$$2\left[\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(s)\space\text{d}s+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=2\left[\frac{1}{4}\left[\sin(s)\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=$$
$$2\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=2\left[\frac{1--1}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=$$
$$2\left[\frac{1+1}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=2\left[\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=2\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]-\frac{2}{3}=1+\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\pi}{2}$$